# MultiTrigger.Conditions for a TextBoxStyle that verifies NullOrWhiteSpace

Tags: c#, .net, validation, multitrigger

I need to trigger a style for the NameTextBox, so that, when the input name is null or white space, the TextBox colours itself in red. The style is created, put how do I associate it with this condition?
Now, this is the condition for it, but does not include whitespace:

```
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="Necessity"
                   Value="Mandatory" />
        <Condition Property="Text"
                   Value="" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't really like this interface personally, IDataErrorInfo should have you covered: http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/

Another solution: Add an "IMultiValueConverter" to your MultiBinding, and trim the text there. Then your MultiBinding.Condition will get an empty string even if the box is filled with spaces.